# Monitoring video card memory temperature

Tags: memory, vga, temperature

I've recently installed a new cooler in my video card, and i want to see if the memory heatsinks it included, are installed correctly and are doing their job.

I've already tried Riva Tuner, GPU-Z, Expert Tool (my video card manufacturer's program) and none of them has that option.

Is there any program that monitors video card temperatures?

Comment: GPU-Z **have** this monitor on "Sensors" tab, but - beware: running GPU-Z himself heats card, I got 45->51 jump in seconds

Comment: No it doesnt:( http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/231/9800gt.gif

I want Memory temperatures not core:)

Answer (score 1):

[HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) do it for me (TMPIN0 in card's section)

[image: HWMonitor window]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure you can monitor the embedded controller. You need to find the correct register. A good program is RW it can read most of the embedded controller.